# Invoking Function in PowerShell via String

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to Invoke a Powershell function "dynamically" using a string. Example

```
$functionToInvoke = "MyFunctionName";

Invoke-Function $functionToInvoke $arg1 $arg2  #  <- what I would like to do
```

Is there any way to achieve this with PowerShell 2.0 ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 &"MyFunctionName" $arg1 $arg2
```

Comment: How would you call a function named start? It seems to get picked up by cmd? Might not be saying that correctly... are there ways around this kind of thing in powershell? or do I just have to name my method differently?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to make variables from the whole thing use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression):

```
function myfunctionname {write-host "$($args[0]) $($args[1])"}
$arg1 = "scripts"
$arg2 = "test"

$functionToInvoke = "MyFunctionName";


Invoke-Expression  "$functionToInvoke $arg1 $arg2"

scripts test
```