# Concisely passing functions as parameters

Tags: powershell, higher-order-functions

This function accepts two values and a function, and calls that function with the two values:

```
function abc ($a, $func, $b) { &$func $a $b }
```

Define a function to pass:

```
function bcd ($x, $y) { $x + $y }
```

Pass `bcd` to `abc`:

```
abc 10 bcd 20
```

The result is `30`.

It appears that the `bcd` function object itself isn't being passed, but the *string* "bcd". Then `abc` invokes `bcd` by its name.

Is this considered an acceptable way to pass a function to another function? Most examples I've seen suggest passing a function in a script block which will be invoked in the receiving function. However that approach is more verbose than the above method.

Comment: If you look at another question like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847923/invoking-function-in-powershell-via-string you are doing what they are doing. It obvioulsly works so there is not issue with it I would think

Comment: You can also use `$function:bcd` to pass the scriptblock.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that it works, as long as the scope doesn't change enough to invalidate the naming. So it's a bit fragile for truly general code; I wouldn't recommend it even in your profile script, for example. (Speaking from some painful experience with insufficiently general profile functions here.)

However, consider this sample, which is even shorter and more robust:

```
function abc($a, $func, $b) { &$func $a $b }
abc 10 { param($a, $b); $a+$b } 20
```

(Prints out `30`.) You can do whatever you'd normally want with that `param` block, including validation.

```
abc 10 {param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$a, [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$b); $a+$b} 20
```

Alternatively, predefine the function like this:

```
$bcd = { param($a, $b); $a+$b }
```

And continue as usual:

```
abc 10 $bcd 20
```

Comment: Hi Nathan! In this case I'd like to pass a defined function by name as opposed to passing an anonymous code block.

Comment: @dharmatech: OK, what's wrong with using the predefinition syntax I mentioned at the point it's defined, and calling the function elsewhere with `&$bcd 1 2`? I think you'll need to expand your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some reason the passed function call needs to be isolated to it's own scope you can simplify that by just passing a script block and invoking it in the function's local scope:

```
function abc($a, $func, $b) {.$func}
abc 10 {$a+$b} 20
30
```

Comment: Hi mjolinor! In this case, I would prefer to have a named function that will be passed over an anonymous script block. However, thanks for this example, it is interesting.